# What is the best way to build message system

Tags: php, mysql

I need to build a message system, send by admin to member, this is my database schema

#### users

```
id primary key
username varchar
```

#### messages

```
id primary key
title varchar
contents varchar
```

#### recipients

```
id primary key
user_id int
message_id int
status varchar'read | deleted | .....'
```

If I create a message, and assign to all member, assumed I have one million member, recipients will have one million data with the message_id and user_id at a time, if admin send message to all member very often, database will increase data pretty fast, is there better structure to deal with this?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not focused enough - there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Sorry for the bad statement, I want to find better method to reduce database storage. save message_id and status to each member as FaddishWorm said might be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rather then store message_id as an int you can store an array of messages and their statuses in JSON.

i.e. message_id {001, 002, 003, 004}

You can take it one step further and store the status as JSON

message_id {001:'read', 002:'unread', 003:'read'}

This way you can manipulate this in PHP/javascript and then put it back in the database so each user has a json string to map the last known state of their messages.

This solution, however is not scalable and doesn't take into account good data normalisation. But I don't have time to explain database design to you - like Jan said this is an open ended question.

Here is a broad, simple overview: https://www.inkling.com/read/access-2010-missing-manual-matthew-macdonald-1st/chapter-2/six-principles-of-database

Here is an answer to a similar question: [Database design for email messaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370647/database-design-for-email-messaging-system)

Comment: If I saved status in user table by Json, it's hard to search how many people had read the message right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That is the tradeoff here.

Comment: I love giving up my time to help people and getting minus 1'd in doing so... Especially when I don't get an explanation why.

Comment: @FaddishWorm I guess that is the fate of a site like this, you will always have the people who are just plain downvoting, for seemingly no reason at all.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! Not that I am in need of employment, but most software/tech companies will look fondly upon a few thousand reputation points. So people should think before down-voting, especially when they are getting support for free.

Comment: @FaddishWorm I also understand what you mean, but maybe you got down-vote because you didn't explain very well how storing a `JSON` text will reduce the database size comparing to adding a row and storing integer IDs. I've also got couple of down-votes where I couldn't understand why, but I believe stackoverflow has quite a healthy community ... (I have also some extra explanation like P.S., to make it more clear to everyone)

Comment: I didn't dv, though I can see where that is comming from. The OP clearly states that there could be *one million members*. So a normalized db is the propably the best way to go. Nonetheless you propose json as a data value, even explaining that this solution will not be scaleable. So this answer is simply not very helpful in this scenario.

Comment: You can shoot down any answer to a DB design question. There are always trade-offs no matter what. I could come up with a 20 page document to answer this question. So where do you draw the line? I offered a new way to think about the problem and some good resources for DB design, I don't see this as a bad thing.

Comment: p.s. to be honest the stack overflow community was better about 3 years ago... It felt more like a university tutor helping a student then your answer being judged like it was a job interview

Answer (score 1):

Sending a single message to a member or couple of members should not be a problem at all, however if you want to send something to all members, then I'd suggest to add an extra layer to your messaging system to implement a notification-like messages as well.

You will lose the message status (e.g. read, unread, etc.) however I think they should not be really important in that case.

I suggest to add the logic that if there was a message assigned to for example UserID `0`, then show it to all members. Of course you need to delete it at some point, so it's not disturbing the members or you can have a different styling for this kind of notification/messages as well - for example they might stuck above the inbox, etc.

P.S. It's not answering your actual question, but I thought it's worth suggesting an alternative approach also.

Comment: Lose not Loose* -- How can you say that read or not read is not important? Not sure what you mean by layer, this is very vague.

Comment: @FaddishWorm, Oh thanks, yeap, it was a typo ... well, I meant to implement something like a one-way notification system, instead of using the messaging system to notify the members.